# kdevelop no valid executable specified

Tags: c++, execution, building, kdevelop

I've just installed kdevelop 4.1 , then created a normal hello world , build is ok but when i press execute it gives me (no valid executable specified) any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meh, the launch configuration - our biggest usability problem...

1. Go to Run -> Configure Launches
2. select your project to the left
3. hit the "+" button
4. to the right, select your project target
5. optionally add a build dependency (again, select e.g. your target).

that should be it.

*/me really wants to rewrite this dialog...*

Comment: That doesn't really help me.  In particular, from my view a compiler *produces* an executable, what exactly am I pointing it at?  The execute I want it to create?  It displays an error about not being able to find the executable.  So if not that, then what?

Comment: @Fred: KDevelop is not a compiler, it does not produce any executable. Your toolchain, i.e. make files, probably generated by CMake or QMake, run a compiler which then produce an executable. KDevelop just runs make and tries to find targets which you can use in the dialog here. I suggest you understand your toolchain first.

Answer (score 0):

After following the steps provided by milianw. In case it doesn't work, follow this steps:

1. Go to Run >> Current Launch Configuration
2. choose the current file name you are trying to compile.